# Runtime Error 438: This object does not support this property or method"

Tags: excel, ms-word, vba

I am new to VBA code within Excel. I have written some code that opens a Word document, searches for values in sequence and replaces the values with values extracted from the Excel workbook. Probably not the quickest way of doing it but it works. I need to "SaveAs" a different file name, ultimately this will need to be uploaded to SharePoint using the same sub, but I will cross that bridge when I get there. Below is my code:

```
Sub SLAProposal()

ThisCustomer = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dashboard").Range("C9").Value
Set wordapp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
wordapp.documents.Open "C:\temp\SLATemp.docx"
wordapp.Visible = True


wordapp.Selection.Find.Text = "<<ClientName>>"
wordapp.Selection.Find.Execute
wordapp.Selection = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dashboard").Range("C9").Value
wordapp.Selection.EndOf


wordapp.Selection.Find.Text = "<<inrate>>"
wordapp.Selection.Find.Execute
wordapp.Selection = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SLA Costing").Range("J20").Value
wordapp.Selection.EndOf

wordapp.Selection.Find.Text = "<<inrate>>"
wordapp.Selection.Find.Execute
wordapp.Selection = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SLA Costing").Range("J20").Value
wordapp.Selection.EndOf


wordapp.Selection.Find.Text = "<<afterrate>>"
wordapp.Selection.Find.Execute
wordapp.Selection = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SLA Costing").Range("K20").Value
wordapp.Selection.EndOf

wordapp.Selection.Find.Text = "<<afterrate>>"
wordapp.Selection.Find.Execute
wordapp.Selection = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SLA Costing").Range("K20").Value
wordapp.Selection.EndOf

wordapp.Selection.Find.Text = "<<otherrate>>"
wordapp.Selection.Find.Execute
wordapp.Selection = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SLA Costing").Range("L20").Value
wordapp.Selection.EndOf

wordapp.Selection.Find.Text = "<<agreement>>"
wordapp.Selection.Find.Execute
wordapp.Selection = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SLA Costing").Range("J7").Value
wordapp.Selection.EndOf

wordapp.Selection.Find.Text = "<<hours>>"
wordapp.Selection.Find.Execute
wordapp.Selection = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SLA Costing").Range("J5").Value
wordapp.Selection.EndOf

wordapp.Selection.Find.Text = "<<inrate>>"
wordapp.Selection.Find.Execute
wordapp.Selection = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SLA Costing").Range("J20").Value
wordapp.Selection.EndOf

wordapp.Selection.Find.Text = "<<retainer>>"
wordapp.Selection.Find.Execute
wordapp.Selection = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SLA Costing").Range("J13").Value
wordapp.Selection.EndOf

wordapp.Selection.Find.Text = "<<servicedescription>>"
wordapp.Selection.Find.Execute
wordapp.Selection = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SLA Costing").Range("K17").Value
wordapp.Selection.EndOf

wordapp.Selection.Find.Text = "<<hoursval>>"
wordapp.Selection.Find.Execute
wordapp.Selection = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SLA Costing").Range("J14").Value
wordapp.Selection.EndOf

wordapp.Selection.Find.Text = "<<retainer>>"
wordapp.Selection.Find.Execute
wordapp.Selection = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SLA Costing").Range("J13").Value
wordapp.Selection.EndOf

wordapp.Selection.Find.Text = "<<addons>>"
wordapp.Selection.Find.Execute
wordapp.Selection = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SLA Costing").Range("J15").Value
wordapp.Selection.EndOf

wordapp.Selection.Find.Text = "<<total>>"
wordapp.Selection.Find.Execute
wordapp.Selection = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SLA Costing").Range("J17").Value
wordapp.Selection.EndOf

wordapp.Selection.Find.Text = "<<month>>"
wordapp.Selection.Find.Execute
wordapp.Selection = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Lookup Table").Range("P1").Value
wordapp.Selection.EndOf

wordapp.Selection.Find.Text = "<<year>>"
wordapp.Selection.Find.Execute
wordapp.Selection = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Lookup Table").Range("P2").Value
wordapp.Selection.EndOf

wordapp.Selection.Find.Text = "<<maxusers>>"
wordapp.Selection.Find.Execute
wordapp.Selection = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SLA Costing").Range("K21").Value
wordapp.Selection.EndOf

wordapp.documents.SaveAs2 "C:\temp\SLATemp1.docx"


End Sub
```

I am getting a Runtime Error 438: This object does not support this property or method" when it hits:

```
wordapp.documents.SaveAs2 "C:\temp\SLATemp1.docx"
```

Can anyone advise why this is the case?

Thanks,
Steven

Comment: Add the line `Option Explicit` at the top of the module and hit F9 to Compile.  This will help "force" you to properly declare and handle your variables, objects, etc.  Once it compiles completely, run the code, and [edit] your question with the updated code and error info if you still can't get it going

Comment: I don't usually work with word, but you've checked that it's supposed to be `.SaveAs2`, not `.SaveAs`?

Comment: You haven't specified which document to save the neither of the save as methods is a member of the Documents collection. Try: wordapp.ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 "C:\temp\SLATemp1.docx"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because the `Documents` collection has no method `SaveAs`. You need to address a specific `Document` object.

Declare and set a variable for the Word document:

```
Dim wordDoc as Word.Document
Set wordDoc = wordapp.Documents.Open("file path here")
```

Later, you can use this object to specifically save *this* document:

```
wordDoc.SaveAs2 "file path here"
```

At the end of the Sub you should explicitly release the Word objects:

```
Set wordDoc = Nothing
Set wordapp = Nothing
```

And, if you're not going to be using `wordapp` anymore:

```
wordapp.Quit
```

This is especially important if you don't `wordapp.Visible = True` because otherwise the Word application will be left running in memory - once for every time the macro is run - and they won't end until Windows is shut down (or someone does it using the Task Manager).

Comment: Thank You Cindy. I've made the changes suggested, all makes sense to me. However, I get an error now when opening the word document: Runtime Error 5147. Sorry we couldn't find your file. Was it moved, renamed or deleted. The file path is definitely correct: Set wordDoc = wordapp.Documents.Open("C:\Temp\SLATemp.docx")

Comment: Forget my last comment. This worked perfectly. I needed to create a new word document for some reason, once I did that no issues at all. Thank You!

Comment: Glad it's working... If you want a new document, use wordApp.Documents.Add("filepath") instead of Documents.Open :-)

Comment: How about opening a file stored in a SharePoint Online library? Its easy enough to save to a library by using the URL to the library as the file path. But I have found that opening a document using a similar concept doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Stevennel That's different question and should be asked in a new Question. Be sure to use a SharePoint-related tag so that people with SharePoint experience also see it.

Answer (score -1):

```
 wordapp.documents.SaveAs2 "C:\temp\SLATemp1.docx"
```

should be

```
 Thisdocument.saveas "C:\temp\SLATemp1.docx"
```

Comment: `ThisDocument` certainly will *not* work in code running from Excel! It only works for the document in which the macro code is contained and should generally not be used. `ActiveDocument` should be used instead, but also wouldn't work in code running from Excel unless `wordapp.` is in front of it.

Comment: Whoops, you're right - missed that it was running from Excel - My bad